# BIRT: creating custom dataSetRow / using dataSetRow in js

Tags: java, birt

Scenario
I have some report with groups Mark && Customer (String)
price - is decimal, id is int

---

| Mark     | [price] | {expresion} |    //in price in group of Mark

| Customer | [id]    |             |

---

price has aggregateOn Mark and aggregateFunction SUM

in {expresion}  I need to show rounded value of [price] with next rule(script on render) :

```
if(
Total.sum(BirtMath.round(dataSetRow["PRICE"])) != BirtMath.round(Total.sum(dataSetRow["PRICE"])) )
{
 this.getStyle().color ='$COLOR$'
}
```

dataSetRow["PRICE"] have all price`s. but I need only those who is in group Mark
somtink like grouped(dataSetRow["PRICE"],"Mark")

Questions : 
1: How to do this in javascript function? 
2: If it is not possible , how to do this by another way ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to write a javascript function in the initialize method of the Report Design.
passing the parameter "Price"

```
// inizialize
function myRoundCheck(obj,price) {
  if( Total.sum(BirtMath.round(price)) != BirtMath.round(Total.sum(price)) ) {
    obj.getStyle().color ='$COLOR$';
  }
}

// on render
myRoundCheck(this,dataSetRow["PRICE"]);
```

Comment: Total is birt`s agregation js library http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Scripting#Aggregates_.28Totals.29